# Having problems with Time Warner Cable Internet

Tags: ethernet

I live in Appleton, WI. As the title states I subscribe to Time Warner Cable. I subscribe to the 50DL and 5UL package. From the morning until around 10PM my internet is fine. However, from 10PM-3AM my connection is very sporadic. I play online games, and competing is very hard when I have 2k-9k ping for minutes at a time. The spikes only last around 5 minutes, but it happens often throughout the time frame. The odd thing is, my teamspeak connection does not drop, and I can hear my friends perfectly, despite having very high ping in team speak as well, but my friends hear me distorted. This leads me to believe it is an upload problem, but I need advice from people more knowledgeable.

Here's some info I can provide:

- I'm using a wired connection.
- The issue happens to all devices in the house.
- My computer is virus free.
- I am the only person connected to the modem (wired or wireless)
- Reset my modem to factory default and made a complex pass code for wireless.
- [Downstream and Upstream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQosj.png)

I vaguely remember having more than a single upstream channel. Is there anything I can do short of getting a TWC tech to come out and fix it?

Thank you for the help, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Home networking questions are off topic here. You can consider asking this on [su].